# gitlab runner shell executer path finding problems

Tags: docker, visual-studio, gitlab

I'm kinda stuck in how to deploy something.

As a dotnet developer I created a webapp (just the simple weatherforecastteamplte) and tried to deploy this.

My ci-cd has 3 stages: build, test and deploy.
My first approach was to use aa ssh key to ssh into my buildserver and transfer the files, because I had gitlab runner running on my gitlab server rather than my buildserver.
For security reasons and other reasons , I have installed gitlab-runner on my buildserver.

My buildserver includes all the tools I nedd: docker, docker-compose, dotnet-npm, ...

So i registered a new runner with shell.
It starts to build the image but when it comes in my dokcerfile it gets stuck because it can't find the cproj file. Currently I have been trying to figure out where the executer is looking for the project file but currently I can't figure it out.

Hope someone can help me.

my dockerfile (generated by visual studio':

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Test/Test.csproj", "Test/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Test/Test.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Test"
RUN dotnet build "Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

my gitlab ci cd file:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest

stages:   
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
before_script:  
  - dotnet restore Test.sln

build:
  stage: build

  tags: 
    - dev

  script:
    - 'dotnet build --no-restore Test.sln'

tests:
  stage: test

  tags: 
    - dev
  script:
    - 'dotnet test --no-restore Test.sln'

deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  
  tags:
    - dev  
  before_script: 
    - cd Test       
  script: 
  - 'docker build - < Dockerfile'
```